# Flutter Dialog Dismiss Required Before Further Action

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, flutter-appbar, flutter-dialog

I'm trying to make a popup menu for my appbar, but when the menu is open, I cannot press a button on the scaffold before dismissing it first. This is similarly true for dialog widgets.

How can I override this behavior? I wish for widgets like popupmenu and dialog to behave the same, and be dismissable in a similar way, except not block any other interactions when clicking outside barrier.

Comment: Can you provide sample snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Just invoke the method `showDialog()` that have a bool `barrierDismissible`. Pass it to `true`.

Example :

```
showDialog(
    barrierDismissible: true,
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text("Dismiss Barrier"),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            ),
            ...
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: this bool is true by default, not relevant to my question. the situation is I want to click buttons where the dark background usually is without double clicking (1. dismiss 2. onpressed)

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use [OverlayEntry](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/OverlayEntry-class.html)
2. Follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOEyJ0ct0Sg) to understand the
   different between ShowDialog and OverlayEntry

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend anyone who runs into this problem to use [flutter_smart_dialog](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_smart_dialog).
Call `SmartDialog.show(...)` and specify `usePenetrate: true`.
Otherwise follow [Drogbut's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72532551/18574279)